# Regular expression in r. Grouping & Capturing

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I'm trying to use regexp in R cran, using the library `stringr`. I was studing `str_match` and `str_replace` functions. I don't understand why they give different results when I use parentheses for Grouping :

```
library(stringr)
s<-"(.+?)( PIAZZALE | SS)(.+?)([0-9]{5})"

a<-str_match("MONT SS DPR   PIAZZALE CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   47838",perl(s))
b<-str_replace("MONT SS DPR   PIAZZALE CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   47838",perl(s), "\\2")

a[3]
#[1] " PIAZZALE "
b
#[1] " SS"
```

Comment: it works correctly. The seond one replaces the whole string with the string present inside the group index 2. I don't know what's your problem with this.

Comment: I think his problem is that the output of str_match[3] and the str_replace here should be equivalent.

Comment: Yes. I expect the output to be equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using just the expression `s` instead of `perl(s)`:

```
library(stringr)
s<-"(.+?)( PIAZZALE | SS)(.+?)([0-9]{5})"

a<-str_match("MONT SS DPR   PIAZZALE CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   47838",s)
b<-str_replace("MONT SS DPR   PIAZZALE CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   47838",s, "\\2")

a[3]
#[1] " PIAZZALE "
b
#[1] " PIAZZALE "
```

I've had a look in the documentation for this library:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf

It suggests that while the `str_replace` method can accept POSIX patterns by default and also perl patterns if supplied, the `str_match` can only accept POSIX style patterns and will treat the pattern as such if supplied with a perl pattern. The reason they were supplying different values is that they were using different expression engines. `str_detect` can use perl expressions and returns either `TRUEE` or `FALSE`. could you potentially use the `str_detect` method instead of the match method?

---

### The difference between POSIX and perl that causes this:

The POSIX engine does not recognise lazy (non-greedy) quantifiers.

Your expression

```
(.+?)( PIAZZALE | SS)(.+?)([0-9]{5})
```

would be seen as the perl equivalent of

```
(.+)( PIAZZALE | SS)(.+)([0-9]{5})
```

Where the first quantified class `.+` would match as much as it can (the full string) before backtracking and evaluating the rest of the expression. It is successful when the first quantified class `.+` comes all the way back from the end of the string and consumes the characters `MONT SS DPR`    leaving only  `SS` for the second capture group `a[3]`

### Simplified Explanation of Engine Inner Workings

Here is a simplified explanation of how the different engines are processing your string. All of your quantifiers/alternation are directly wrapped in capture groups so the numbered quantifiers in the following examples are also your capture groups:

**Perl:**

```
Quantifier 1: "M"
Quantifier 2: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

Quantifier 1: "MO"
Quantifier 2: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

Quantifier 1: "MON"
Quantifier 2: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

Quantifier 1: "MONT"
Quantifier 2: " SS"
Quantifier 3: " "
Quantifier 4: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

Quantifier 1: "MONT"
Quantifier 2: " SS"
Quantifier 3: " D"
Quantifier 4: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

...

Quantifier 1: "MONT"
Quantifier 2: " SS"
Quantifier 3: " DPR   PIAZZALE CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   "
Quantifier 4: "47838"

SUCCESS
```

**POSIX:**

```
Quantifier 1: "MONT SS DPR   PIAZZALE CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   47838"
Quantifier 2: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

Quantifier 1: "MONT SS DPR   PIAZZALE CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   4783"
Quantifier 2: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

Quantifier 1: "MONT SS DPR   PIAZZALE CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   478"
Quantifier 2: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

Quantifier 1: "MONT SS DPR   PIAZZALE CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   47"
Quantifier 2: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

...

Quantifier 1: "MONT SS DPR   P"
Quantifier 2: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

Quantifier 1: "MONT SS DPR   "
Quantifier 2: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

Quantifier 1: "MONT SS DPR  "
Quantifier 2: " PIZZALE "
Quantifier 3: "CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   47838"
Quantifier 4: FAILED - MUST BACKTRACK

...

Quantifier 1: "MONT SS DPR  "
Quantifier 2: " PIZZALE "
Quantifier 3: "CADORNA, 1A RICCIONE   "
Quantifier 4: "47838"

SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'd like to understand why it's different

Comment: @dax90 I've had a look in the documentation for this library: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf It suggests that while the `str_replace` method can accept perl patterns the `str_match` can only accept POSIX style patterns and will treat the pattern as such if supplied with a perl pattern. The reason they were supplying different values is that they were using different expression engines. `str_detect` can use perl expressions and returns either `TRUEE` or `FALSE`. could you potentially use the `str_detect` method instead of the match method?

Comment: That's a good answer. But I still don't understand how `perl` engine is different from  `POSIX` evaluating my `s`  object. Why `b<-str_replace("string,s, "\\2")` is different from `b<-str_replace("string,perl(s), "\\2")` ? What changes in the interpretation of `s`?

Comment: Thank you so mutch! That's very helpful and complete!